# View factory specific to Namespace on Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, activeadmin, factory

I need to implement two namespaces in active admin and have different menu design for each.
My namespaces works well and I use view_factory to redifine my nav bar but when I try to set my view for a specific namespace, this view is set for every namespaces.

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :dashboard do |dashboard|
   dashboard.view_factory.global_navigation = MyNavigation
  end
end

class MyNavigation < ActiveAdmin::Component
  def build menu, options = {}
    # my specific stuff
  end
end
```

I'm using Active Admin 0.5.1 and it should work with multiple namespaces http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/activeadmin-0-5-0-is-released/

If someone knows where I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a hack, needs to create a new ActiveAdmin::ViewFactory.new for each workspace and duplicate common views (you can't create for all workspaces with config.view_factory...)

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :dashboard do |dashboard|
    dashboard.view_factory = ActiveAdmin::ViewFactory.new
    dashboard.view_factory.global_navigation = MyNavigation
    dashboard.view_factory.footer = CommonFooter
  end
  config.namespace :dashboard do |admin|
    admin.view_factory = ActiveAdmin::ViewFactory.new
    admin.view_factory.footer = CommonFooter
  end
end
```

It's not very proper and DRY but it works well